# pipeline with Filesystem List Parameter

Tags: jenkins, parameters, jenkins-pipeline, filesystems, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am trying to write a pipeline using the `Filesystem List Parameter` parameter:

[image]

but I am unable to find the correct syntax anywhere, even in Jenkins doc. Do this plugin is allowed in Jenkins pipeline? if so then what will be the syntax?

https://plugins.jenkins.io/filesystem-list-parameter-plugin/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [**Pipeline Syntax** → `input` → `parameters` → `$class: 'FileSystemListParameterDefinition'`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-input-step/#input-wait-for-interactive-input):

```groovy
    stages {
            stage('Parameters') {
                steps {
                    script {
    
                        // one parameter
                        def value = input( message: 'Select parameter value:',
                            parameters: [
                                [$class: 'FileSystemListParameterDefinition',
                                    name: 'SingleFileSystemObject',
                                    description: 'Single file system object',
                                    nodeName: 'master',
                                    path: '/',
                                    selectedType: 'ALL',
                                    formSelectType: 'SINGLE_SELECT',
                                    regexIncludePattern: '',
                                    regexExcludePattern: '',
                                    sortReverseOrder: false
                                ] // parameters
                            ] // input
                        )
    
                        // more parameters, displayed on a separate parameter input page
                        Map values = input( message: 'Select parameter values:',
                            parameters: [
                                [$class: 'FileSystemListParameterDefinition',
                                    name: 'SingleFileSystemObject',
                                    description: 'Single file system object',
                                    nodeName: 'master',
                                    path: '/',
                                    selectedType: 'ALL',
                                    formSelectType: 'SINGLE_SELECT',
                                    regexIncludePattern: '',
                                    regexExcludePattern: '',
                                    sortReverseOrder: false
                                ],
    
                                [$class: 'FileSystemListParameterDefinition',
                                    name: 'MultipleFileSystemObjects',
                                    description: 'Multiple file system objects',
                                    nodeName: 'master',
                                    path: '/',
                                    selectedType: 'ALL',
                                    formSelectType: 'MULTI_SELECT',
                                    regexIncludePattern: '',
                                    regexExcludePattern: '',
                                    sortReverseOrder: false
                                ]
                            ] // parameters
                        ) // input
                    
                        echo value
                        print values['SingleFileSystemObject']
                        print values['MultipleFileSystemObjects']
                    }
                }
        }
    }
```

#### Console Output

E.g.:

```
...
[Pipeline] echo
root
[Pipeline] echo
bin
[Pipeline] echo
home,usr
...
```

Comment: Its coming us in the runtime not in the default. 
`Input requested`

Also I am getting the below error, folder name is 12000

`WARNING: Unknown parameter(s) found for class type 'alex.jenkins.plugins.FileSystemListParameterDefinition': formSelectType` 

next one

`hudson.remoting.ProxyException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object '12000' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'java.util.Map'`

Comment: @Senthil13 What do you mean by "_runtime_" vs. "_default_"? Did you follow the link I supplied and read: "_If just one parameter is listed, its value will become the value of the input step. If multiple parameters are listed, the return value will be a map keyed by the parameter names_". So, if you have just one paramer use `def value = input ( ... )`.

Comment: what I meant by runtime is, when I do build with parameter, the variable is not showing, but when clicking the build then while runtime in the console output it comes as a link like `Input requested` then I have to select the value from the dropdown.

Comment: @Senthil13 After starting the build hover over the stage that uses parameter(s) to get a popup where you have a link to open the parameter input page. I agree, that's not very intuitive.

Comment: thanks for the help.